# Segmentation fault upon calling delete

Tags: c++, memory-management, segmentation-fault

gdb backtrace:

```
#0  0x0040cea9 in free () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#1  0x0033c741 in operator delete(void*) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x080654b6 in mesh::calculateMeanNormalsPerVertex (this=0x807d684)
    at /home/brent/Desktop/protCAD/src/math/mesh.cc:230
#3  0x0805638f in buildCubes (argc=4, argv=0xbffff3e4)
    at /home/brent/Desktop/protCAD/src/driver/executeCubes.cc:163
#4  main (argc=4, argv=0xbffff3e4)
    at /home/brent/Desktop/protCAD/src/driver/executeCubes.cc:297
```

Declaration and `delete` call in `mesh.cc`:

```
vector<vector<int> > faceIndicesPerVertex (vertexArray.size());
...
delete[] &faceIndicesPerVertex;    //line 230
```

I'm sure I have this wrong, but I've tried a few different ways of calling delete there, but none seem to compile except the above. What's the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to `delete` any stack-allocated object, stack-allocated `vector` object included - it will be destroyed and its memory will be reclaimed when the object goes out of scope. Trying to `delete` a stack-allocated object leads to undefined behavior (crash in your case).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `faceIndicesPerVertex` is not an array, so you cant call `delete[]`.

And second, `faceIndicesPerVertex` is a local variable. This means it's on the stack. This means you can't use `delete` on it.

Only use `delete` on objects you allocate in the heap with `new`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to call `delete[]`. It's automatically allocated variable/container, it will be automatically destroyed/freed memory.

Call `delete` when you call `new` and vise versa. The same for `new[]` and `delete[]`.

Answer (score 1):

`faceIndicesPerVertex` is not a pointer, it was allocated on stack. You can't delete it, and you  don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

`faceIndicesPerVertex` is not a pointer, so `delete[]` is not required.
`faceIndicesPerVertex` is a `vector` so `delete[]` will not even work.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `delete` is used only for deallocating memory from the heap. You cannot delete stack allocated memory using `delete`. As a general rule, `delete` memory only if you dynamically allocated it using `new`. I also had some problems with the usage of `new/delete`. If you follow the general rule of using `new` and `delete` in pairs, you should be fine.